# How to properly test Angular's $http success and error promises with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have such controller:

```
$scope.signIn = (user) ->
      if user.email != '' and user.password != ''
        UserService.signIn(user)
```

I have such service:

```
 signIn: (user) ->
        $http.post '/user/signin', user

        .success (data) ->
          AuthService.set 'email', data.user.local.email

        .success () ->
          $state.go 'auth.profile'

        .error () ->
          throw Error(err)
```

I have such test so far:

```
describe 'AuthController Unit Tests', ->

  beforeEach module('kreditorenApp')

  AuthController  = undefined
  scope           = undefined
  AuthService     = undefined
  UserService     = undefined
  $httpBackend    = undefined
  $controller     = undefined
  $location       = undefined
  user            = undefined
  HTTPInterceptor = undefined
  $alert          = undefined

  resUser =
    "status": "OK"
    "error": "Erfolgreich Authentifiztiert"
    "type": "success"
    "token": "TOKEN STRING"
    "user":
      "__v": 0
      "_id": "5512a0dfcbc8ea974647f493"
      "local":
        "password": "HASH STRING"
        "email": "dieter"


  beforeEach inject(($rootScope, _$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _UserService_, _AuthService_, _$location_, _$alert_, _HTTPInterceptor_) ->

    scope         = $rootScope.$new()
    $controller   = _$controller_
    $httpBackend  = _$httpBackend_
    $location     = _$location_
    UserService   = _UserService_
    AuthService   = _AuthService_
    HTTPInterceptor = _HTTPInterceptor_

    # Stubs
    #
    httpFake = () ->
      bla:
        "bla"

    userFake = () ->
      signIn:
        "SUCCESS"

    # Spies
    #
    spyOn(HTTPInterceptor, 'response').and.callFake(httpFake)
    # spyOn(UserService, 'signIn').and.callFake(userFake)

    $httpBackend.expectPOST('/user/signin', user).respond(200, {user":"local":"email":"emperorRudolf"})
    $httpBackend.expectGET('app/controller/auth/auth.html').respond(200)
    $httpBackend.expectGET('app/controller/auth/partials/profile.html').respond(200)

    AuthController = $controller('AuthController', $scope:scope)
  )

  afterEach ->
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation()
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest()

  it 'should signIn user & ui-route to auth.profile & invoke HTTPInterceptor', ->

    # Tests
    #
    scope.signIn ({email:'mail', password:'pass'})
    $httpBackend.flush()

    #expect(HTTPInterceptor.response).toHaveBeenCalled
    #expect many more things later
```

The test is failing with

```
 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'data.user')
```

I want to mock out as few as possible.

*Edit:* The data object is always undefined. `$http`'s rather unique `.success` method is not accessible or known to my tests. How do I test this properly?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is done, for an `error`. Grab a reference to the promise that we reject, provide an error message, and catch the error. I am still working on the `.success promise` and will update as soon as I got it running. I think I will switch to Sinon because this seems much to complicated for testing my controller/service duo.

```
describe 'AuthController Unit Tests', ->

  beforeEach module('myApp')

  UserService = undefined
  httpMock = undefined
  $q = undefined
  $scope = undefined

  beforeEach module('myApp', ($provide) ->
    httpMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('$http', ['post'])
    $provide.value('$http', httpMock)
    return
  )

  beforeEach inject((_$controller_, $rootScope, _$q_, _UserService_) ->
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    $controller = _$controller_
    $q = _$q_
    UserService = _UserService_

    AuthController = $controller('AuthController',
      $scope: $scope
    )
  )

  it 'should catch an error', ->

    errorMsg = 'Unauthorized'
    defer = $q.defer()
    defer.reject(errorMsg)
    httpMock.post.and.returnValue(defer.promise)

    UserService.signIn('1').catch (error) ->
      expect(error).toEqual(errorMsg)

    $scope.$digest();
    return
```

Please note the `return` after `$provide.value('$http', httpMock)` is mandatory otherwise CoffeeScript will come and haunt you. Props to [Simon Bailey's Angular Testing Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/angularjs-testing-cookbook) for providing help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You code posts to `/user/signin`, and expects to get back a response body containing a user:

```
 $http.post '/user/signin', user

    .success (data) ->
        AuthService.set 'email', data.user.local.email
```

But when you're mocking the backend, you make it return the following:

```
$httpBackend.expectPOST('/user/signin', user).respond(200, {"asd":"asd"})
```

So, obviously, trying to access `user.local.email` on the object `{"asd":"asd"}` won't work.

Comment: You have a keen eye friend, I should add, it makes no difference. The data object is undefined anyway no matter what I return. I console.logged out the returned data object and it is always undefined. This is the object I usually mock-return: `resUser =  "user":"local":"email":"emperorRudolf"`. Just saying this is no syntax issue, but rather a problem with the rather strange `.success` method of `$http` module.

Comment: Could you please reduce the test and remove all the noise (interceptors, requests for html, etc.). Also post the complete stack trace and tell us the line number associated with the error.